# Spring boot debug in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, docker-compose, remote-debugging

I would like to debug my Spring boot application using the remote debugger in Eclipse.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=root
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=leblanc
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
  gomoku-web:
    image: gomoku-web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8888:8888
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/root?useSSL=false",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "root",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "leblanc",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update",
        "fr.leblanc.gomoku.engineUrl" : "http://gomoku-engine:9000"
      }'
      CATALINA_OPTS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:8888"
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  gomoku-engine:
    image: gomoku-engine:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db:
```

In Eclipse, I created a Remote Java Application with Host "localhost" and port "8888" but when I try to launch it, it says :

```
Failed to connect to remote VM
com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException
```

Am I missing something ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem

I needed to replace

```
  CATALINA_OPTS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=0.0.0.0:8888"
```

with

```
  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8888,server=y,suspend=n"
```